# Unbound constructor with Arrays

Tags: ocaml

```
let somethin Arr = 
    let lgh = Array.length Arr in
    lgh;;
```

This simple code doesnt compile, giving me "Error: Unbound constructor Arr" error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml variables can't start with an uppercase letter. Use `arr` instead of `Arr`.